# How can I get the init code hash of a Solidity contract in Deno?

Tags: javascript, web3js, deno

I'm building a web3 project in Deno, and I'm having a hard time trying to get the init code hash of a contract from the bytecode, how can I achieve that in Deno?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the init code hash of a contract, you have to do `keccak256(bytecode)`, in Deno you can achieve that with the following code:

```
import { keccak256 } from "npm:@ethersproject/keccak256";
import { decode } from "https://deno.land/std@0.180.0/encoding/hex.ts";

const bytecode = '...'; // The bytecode as a hex string (without 0x)
const initCodeHash = keccak256(decode(new TextEncoder().encode(bytecode)));
```

---

This part of the code:

```
decode(new TextEncoder().encode(bytecode))
```

Is equivalent to Node's:

```
Buffer.from(bytecode, 'hex')
```